# Woocommerce coupon discount when item price is less than the discount amount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

From my understanding of how `woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount` works. The discount is calculated as to how much it would discount each item in the cart. For example, if you had 4 items in the cart at $10, and you were to discount one item to be free. Then you would return $2.50 to each product in the cart. Thus discounting one of the products by 100%.

However, let's say that you had a product in the cart that was $1, then instead of discounting $10, the discount applied would be $8.50. Making the discount incorrect.

For this above example the coupon would be calculated as so:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'mb_wcchpi_cpn_disc', 10, 5);
function mb_wcchpi_cpn_disc($discount, $discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $coupon) 
{
    //IF CUSTOM COUPON TYPE
    if ($coupon->type == 'most_expensive_coupon') {       
        //Gets the most expensive item in the cart
        $mostExpensiveItem = FindMaxPricedItem($multiple_products);
        
        //Get the price of the most expensive item in the cart
        $maxPrice = $mostExpensiveItem['price'];

        //GET THE COUPON DISCOUNT AMOUNT
        $amt = floatval($coupon->amount);

        //GET THE DISCOUNT AMOUNT
        $discount = ($amt / 100) * $maxPrice;

        //GET THE ITEMS IN THE CART
        $itemCount = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;

        //DISTRIBUTE EQUALLY ACROSS ALL ITEMS IN CART
        $discount = $discount / $itemCount;
    }

    return $discount;

}
```

How would one handle the edge case of having an item in the cart that is less than the discount amount? Is there a different action than `woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount` to be used for applying a coupon to the cart total instead of per item? Is there a different formula I should be using to come up with the discount?

Comment: Could you find a solution for this?

Comment: Sadly no........

Comment: Same here, this is the first time that I couldn't find any solutions related to WP or WC. I want to have dynamic discount amount based on a coupon. Do you have any ideas? For example 10% for >$50, 20% for >$150